# How to restart puma after deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano3, puma

I'm using Rails, Puma, Capistrano3. I have installed the gem `capistrano3-puma` as well. I started Puma with Puma Jungle https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/upstart

How do I restart Puma during deployment?

Comment: `cap production puma:restart` since stage is required.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can restart manually using the following command

```
bundle exec pumactl -P /home/deploy/.pids/puma.pid restart
```

Make sure you point to the correct pid path.

Comment: Depends how you are deploying your application. Using capistrano, you can write tasks for it and include them in your deployment process, or use something like god http://godrb.com/ which you can also integrate with capistrano

Comment: For me `bundle exec pumactl restart` was enough.

Answer (score 25):

**Production**

If you are using capistrano on production you can:

```
cap production deploy:restart
```

**Development**

If you are on a development environment you can start to look for the pid

```
ps aux | grep puma
```

You will see something like this:

```
user 11654  0.0 13.4 870204 137016 ?       Sl   Jul07   0:39 puma 2.13.4 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [NameOfYourApp]
```

The number next to the username, in this case `11654` is the process id (PID) of puma server. You can kill it manually and restart the server after. Run this command:

```
kill -s 15 11654
```

This command is saying *kill the process with id 11654 using signal SIGTERM (code 15)*. SIGTERM kills the process 'kindly' closing all files, connections, cleaning buffers, etc.

Last you run this command:

```
puma -e development -p 3000 -d
```

Puma will be started again in development mode, listening on port 3000 and the execution will be demonized.

Answer (score 17):

I ran into the issue where I need to restart puma after some environment changes and did not want to do a full deploy of the application.

I only wanted to restart puma and nginx. Here are the commands that worked for me:

```
$ bundle exec cap production deploy:restart
$ bundle exec cap production puma:restart
```

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 3):

Generic answer that will work on any platform and it is supported by Puma server itself, is to use `tmp_restart` plugin.

Add to your `config/puma.rb`

```
plugin :tmp_restart
```

After that just touch the file (`touch tmp/restart.txt`) when you want to restart the puma app.

Source: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/plugin/tmp_restart.rb

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if you are using `capistrano3-puma` gem, you do not need to restart puma explicitly after deployment. There is a task `add_default_hooks` which does `puma:smart_restart` after deployment.

You can see the task list by `cap -vT`. I think `cap puma:restart` will do the work.

Comment: If  you add `install_plugin Capistrano::Puma, load_hooks: true` to your `Capfile` you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
cap production puma:stop
cap production puma:start
```

or

```
cap production puma:restart
```